# How to make nested div scroll using outer scrollbar, while sidebar next to it stays fixed/sticky?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to avoid inner scrollbars for a main content area that is deeply nested within the DOM.

That is working fine right now, however to the left of this nested main content area, there should be a fixed/sticky sidebar that only extends down to the bottom of the visible screen - without overflowing, unlike the page content div to the right of it.

It's easier to illustrate with this image:

[image]

I also made a codepen to illustrate the problem. The problem is the orange sidebar.

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-scooby-cdliqz?file=/index.html

If the yellow row had a fixed height, it would be easy, however I cannot use calc and subtract that height of the yellow div, since it will expand depending on its content.

[image]

Update:

Best solution so far is using ResizeObserver and CSS Variables like @Adam suggested. https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-ishizaka-gtn3e0?file=/index.html

However I still hope to find a pure css way to achieve this layout.

Comment: I'd suggest a resize observer on the top yellow div#first to dynamially change a css variable in the root to control the position of the sidebar and main-content.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your suggestion. I might just end up doing that if I absolutely need to, however if JavaScript indeed really is necessary to achieve this (without too many css hacks), then I might as well reconsider the whole layout.

Comment: @Adam if I did what you suggested, you'd set the orange sidebar div to `calc(100vh - [height of yellow, or perhaps  better, the bottom y coordinate of yellow div])`, right?

Comment: Yep, or just treat it as an element with position:absolute and just set the top and bottom attributes. As with all things it might be a case of suck it and see. Personally I'd just cope with the scroll bar being on the inner element and use grid as the layout but then I'm a bit lazy haha

Comment: That's a pretty cool annotated diagram. What did you use to generate it?

Comment: Thx, https://excalidraw.com/ - and thanks for your advice!!